# Is a closed ball in dual space $E'$ of a normed space $E$ compact with respect to the topology of compact convergence on $E'$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence

Let $E$ be a normed vector space and $\sigma_c(E',E)$ denote the topology of compact convergence on $E'$. It's easy to show that $\sigma_c(E',E)$ is Hausdorff.

Now let $\delta>0$ and $$V_\delta:=\{\varphi\in E':\left\|\varphi\right\|_{E'}\le\delta\}.$$ Clearly, the subspace topology $\left.\sigma_c(E',E)\right|_{V_\delta}$ is Hausdorff as well.

> But how can we show that $V_\delta$ is $\sigma_c(E',E)$-compact? It is clearly $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{E'}$-bounded. Does this already imply the claim?

Comment: $V_{\delta}$ is certainly not norm compact (unless $E$ is f.d.).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You're right. It is norm bounded though.

Comment: On bounded sets the topology of convergence on compacts is the same as the topology of pointwise convergence, so the answer is yes by Alaoglu's Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. The proof is contained essentially in the following fact:

If $E$ is a LCS and $A \subset E'$ is equicontinuous, then the topology of totally bounded convergence and the topology of pointwise convergence coincide on A.

Indeed, assume that this is true. Then $V_\delta$ is equicontinuous and compact in the topology of pointwise convergence due to Banach-Alaouglu theorem. Thus, it is compact in the topology of convergence on totally bounded sets. A fortiori it is compact in the topology of compact convergence.

To prove the foregoing fact fix $f \in A$ and a totally bounded set $K \subset E$. We are going to construct a finite set $F = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\} \subset E$ s.t. $(f + 1/3\;F^\circ) \cap A \subset (f + K^\circ) \cap A$. Let $U \subset E$ be a neighbourhood of $0$ s.t. $A \subset U^\circ$. Since $K$ is totally bounded there exists a finite set $F \subset E$ s.t. $F + 1/3 \; U \supset K$. Assume that $g \in (f + 1/3\; F^\circ) \cap A$. Then $g-f \in 1/3\; F^\circ$ and, therefore, $|(g-f)(x)| \le 1/3$ for all $x \in F$. Now for all $x \in K$ there exists $x' \in F$ s.t. $x-x' \in 1/3\; U$. Therefore
$$|(g-f)(x)| \le |g(x) - g(x')| + |g(x') - f(x')| + |f(x') - f(x)| \le 1,$$
because $f,g \in U^\circ$ and $x-x' \in 1/3\;U$. Thus, $g \in (f + K^\circ) \cap A$.

Therefore, each neighbourhood of $f$ in $A$ in the topology of totally bounded convergence contains a smaller neighbourhood of $f$ in the topology of pointwise convergence. It easily follows that the topologies coincide.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the same argument should show that any $\left\|\;\dot\;\right\|_{E'}$-bounded subset $B\subseteq E'$ is $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_E$-equicontinuous (simply by linearity and boundedness of the operator norms) and hence the topologies of pointwise and compact convergence on $B$ should coincide, right?